# How do I deal with ghost titans without having to constantly monitor them?

Tags: revenge-of-the-titans

I'm progressing through the campaign and am finding ghost titans to be a real pain. I have capacitors and am using them to eliminate the ghosts, but because the capacitor has to be activated manually capacitors require me to constantly monitor the ghosts' approach route for when they appear.

Is there any way to deal with ghost titans *without* requiring constant supervision?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, having now played further, it turns out the **X-Ray Scanner** technology gives most of your turrets the ability to shoot at ghosts - and so means ghosts no longer require direct monitoring. The technology does reduce turret range as a penalty though, but this reduction seems to directly counteract the boost provided by *Optics*, so no change overall.

To unlock **X-Ray Scanner** you first need to unlock the *Scanner*, *Optics* (which needs *Particle Physics*) and *Research Grant* (which requires *Stronger Coffee* (which requires *Extra Coffee Delivery*)).

Comment: I was just about to ask *the exact same question* myself. Thanks for answering it when you figured out the solution!